# How to know a floating QWidget position when it is shown

Tags: qt, position, move, qwidget, window-managers

I'm trying to move a floating QWidget (Qt::window flag ), in a position depending of it's initial position, wich is determined by the window manager.

I can't find a clean way to do it. The first move event is always at position 0,0; and during show event, position is also 0,0.

So the only way for now i've found is something like that :

```
this->firstMoved = false;
this->myFirstMoved = false;
...
void TabWidget::moveEvent( QMoveEvent* event ) 
{
    if( this->firstMoved )
    {
        if(! this->myFirstMoved )
        {   
            this->myMoveMethod();
            this->myFirstMoved = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this->firstMoved = true;
    }
    Superclass::moveEvent( event );
}
```

not as clean as i would have expected. I'm using X11 by the way.

Comment: The second `if`'s condition is always false. Try to implement `showEvent` and get the initial position in it.

Comment: Well, i've tried it with event filteret Qt::show, same problem, position is 0,0
Also the second if is not always false.